# Create pandas dataframe joining dataframes taken from original one and ploting the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I need to create a new dataframe based on dataframes taken from the original one and finally plot the resulting dataframe.

I get the expected output I want but I think there might be a better and cleaner way to do it.

Lets say I have the following `Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"element":["line_1","line_2","line_3","line_4","line_1","line_2","line_4","line_1","line_3","line_4"],"max":[101,110,106,100,102,111,101,103,107,100],"name":["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"]})
```

Which looks like:

```
>>> df
  element  max name
0  line_1  101    A
1  line_2  110    A
2  line_3  106    A
3  line_4  100    A
4  line_1  102    B
5  line_2  111    B
6  line_4  101    B
7  line_1  103    C
8  line_3  107    C
9  line_4  100    C
```

Then I use the following code to use the `name` column to filter and create new dataframes which I will finally join to get the resulting dataframe I want to plot.

```
names = df.name.unique()

data = pd.DataFrame()
for name in names:
    dfJoin = df[df.name==name]
    dfJoin = dfJoin[["element","max"]]
    dfJoin.columns = ["element","max" + name]
    dfJoin = dfJoin.set_index("element")
    data = data.join(dfJoin, how="outer")

data.plot(marker="o")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

I'm not sure that's the best way to code it but I get the expected `Dataframe` data which looks like:

```
>>> data
         maxA   maxB   maxC
element                    
line_1    101  102.0  103.0
line_2    110  111.0    NaN
line_3    106    NaN  107.0
line_4    100  101.0  100.0
```

The plot finally shows the below image:
[image]

**My question is**: May there be a better way to do this task? Maybe using `groupby` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can do this with *`pivot_table`*, specifying `max` as the `aggfunc` -

```
df = df.pivot_table(
      index='element', 
      columns='name', 
      values='max', 
      aggfunc='max'
     )\
     .add_prefix('max')\
     .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')

df

          maxA   maxB   maxC
element                     
line_1   101.0  102.0  103.0
line_2   110.0  111.0    NaN
line_3   106.0    NaN  107.0
line_4   100.0  101.0  100.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Another option is *`pd.crosstab`* -

```
df = pd.crosstab(
      index=df.element, 
      columns=df.name, 
      values=df['max']
      aggfunc='max'
     )\
     .add_prefix('max')\
     .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')

df

          maxA   maxB   maxC
element                     
line_1   101.0  102.0  103.0
line_2   110.0  111.0    NaN
line_3   106.0    NaN  107.0
line_4   100.0  101.0  100.0
```

Comment: I thought of `pivot_table` as well and did some trials, but then discarded it as I couldn't get the result as I wanted. What you got is exactly what I need :D

Comment: @CedricZoppolo The "name" is the `df.columns.name` property, taken from `df.name` series passed to the `columns` argument. You can remove it by doing `df.columns.name = None`.

Comment: Don't break the chain! `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis='columns')` ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without aggregation (even if it is meaningless), would be to set and unstack an index:

```
xtab = (
    df.set_index(['element', 'name'])
      .unstack(level='name')['max']
      .rename(columns=lambda c: 'max'+c)
)
```

And I get:

```
name      maxA   maxB   maxC
element                     
line_1   101.0  102.0  103.0
line_2   110.0  111.0    NaN
line_3   106.0    NaN  107.0
line_4   100.0  101.0  100.0
```

A possible benefit of this is that you'll get an error if "element" and "name" don't form a unique index, which may serve as a check on the quality of the data.